# Exporting a subset of a SpatialPointsDataFrame

Tags: r, r-sp

I have created a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` using the following code:

```
SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = data4xy,
                       proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=9 ellps=WGS84"))
```

where `data4xy` is a data frame containing 2 columns, `date` is the time stamp associated with each GPS point and `id` is the id of the tracked animal.

From this `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, I would like to export a shapefile using `writeOGR()` for each tracked animal (essentially grouping by `id`).  How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `subset` in a `for` loop or an *apply statement, e.g.:

```
library("sp")
library("rgdal")

data("meuse")  # example data
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

# separate by `soil`
table(meuse$soil)
#  1  2  3 
# 97 46 12 

id_list <- levels(meuse$soil)  # `levels()` for factors, otherwise `unique()`

# subset SpatialPointsDataFrame and write shapefiles
lapply(id_list,
       function(x) { 
         writeOGR(obj=subset(meuse, soil==x), dsn=".",
                  layer=sprintf("meuse_%s", x),
                  driver="ESRI Shapefile")
       })
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! But can you please explain why I need `sprintf()`? I just want to understand the code so I can improve my programming skills.

Comment: I used `sprintf` to create the filenames of the shapefiles, there are many others possibilities to do this ...